# PhpStorm doesn't show autocomplete even after Ctrl+Space

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpstorm

I am learning to code with Symfony in symfonycasts.com and am using PhpStorm.

`Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface` service doesn't load `getRepository()->` suggestions.

This is what I should see typing getRepository():
[image: (1)This is what I should see typing getRepository()]

[image: (2)This is what I should see typing getRepository()]

This is what I see:
[image: (1)This is what I see]

[image: (2)This is what I see]

Other autocomplete libraries seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one way to fix it : it's possible to hint IDE which class is that object can by using `@var` annotation above the variable, e.g.:

```
/** @var \App\Repository\QuestionRepository $repository */ 
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Question::class); 
$repository-> // now you should have autocomplete here :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Phpstorm seems to have issue with the `EntityManagerInterface`, when I use the specific type `EntityManager` instead of interface, the suggestions start working again.